# How can I review comment history on Azure DevOps Pull Requests?

Tags: azure-devops, pull-request

I have noticed that when you modify a comment in a Pull Request, there doesn't seem to be a way to view the history of the comment. As well, comments still allow editing after someone responds to it. One of my colleges is editing comments after he gets a response and our pull requests are not making sense because of it. Is there a history or a way to prevent changes?

Comment: Hi nice, Not get your latest information, is the answer below helpful for you? Or if you have any concern, feel free to share it here

Answer (score 1):

Sorry but as I know it's impossible. Besides, similar issue has been submitted in this earlier suggestion ticket linked here:
[Disable comment editing (i.e. add, edit, delete, and state change) in completed pull request](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/idea/365593/disable-comment-editing-ie-add-edit-delete-and-sta.html)

In addition, we can use below API to get [Pull Request Thread Comments](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/git/pull%20request%20thread%20comments/get?view=azure-devops-rest-5.1) to check lastUpdatedDate and publishedDate.

```
GET https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/git/repositories/{repositoryId}/pullRequests/{pullRequestId}/threads/{threadId}/comments/{commentId}?api-version=5.1
```